# MySQL combine multiple rows into one based on matching dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Sample of my data:

```
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+--+
| ID | startdate  |  enddate   |  status   | lengthofstay |  |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+--+
|  1 | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-16 | transfer  |            1 |  |
|  1 | 2018-02-16 | 2018-02-22 | discharge |            6 |  |
|  2 | 2018-03-05 | 2018-03-08 | discharge |            3 |  |
|  1 | 2018-11-01 | 2018-11-03 | transfer  |            2 |  |
|  1 | 2018-11-03 | 2018-11-20 | transfer  |           17 |  |
|  1 | 2018-11-20 | 2018-11-21 | discharge |            1 |  |
|  2 | 2019-05-15 | 2019-05-20 | discharge |            5 |  |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+--+
```

There are two problems I would like to address. 
First, I would like to combine rows with matching IDs into a single row based on matching startdate and enddate, while also taking the sum of the lengthofstay (datediff between startdate and enddate).
Second problem, I have repeating IDs, which entered the system at a later date on a separate occasion, that I would like to keep as a separate observation.

Here is what my ideal output would look like:

```
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| ID | startdate  |  enddate   |  status   | lengthofstay |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-22 | discharge |            7 |
|  2 | 2018-03-05 | 2018-03-08 | discharge |            3 |
|  1 | 2018-11-01 | 2018-11-21 | discharge |           20 |
|  2 | 2019-05-15 | 2019-05-20 | discharge |            5 |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

I don't have a lot of experience in MySQL and I am not sure if this is possible to do with a join, concat or group by with rollup. I understand having repeating IDs on separate occasion is an additional problem, so I am thinking of involving another identifier based on how far apart startdate is from the last enddate for each unique ID (margin of 3 days for example), but I don't know how to do that either.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321741/combining-multiple-rows-to-make-up-a-date-range) but with no answer.

I appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. Here is one way to solve it using window functions, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select
    id,
    min(startdate) startdate,
    max(enddate) enddate,
    last_status status,
    sum(lengthofstay) lengthofstay
from (
    select
        t.*,
        last_value(status) over(partition by id, rn1 - rn2) last_status
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            row_number() over(order by startdate) rn1,
            row_number() over(partition by id order by startdate) rn2
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by
    id,
    last_status,
    rn1 - rn2
order by min(startdate)
```

The query works by ranking the records over two different partitions; the difference between the ranks gives you the group it belongs to. Then, `last_value()` can be used to retrieve the last status in each group. The last step is aggregation.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bfbf7349225e5910e800e79c361121b1)**:

```
id | startdate  | enddate    | status    | lengthofstay
-: | :--------- | :--------- | :-------- | -----------:
 1 | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-22 | discharge |            7
 2 | 2018-03-05 | 2018-03-08 | discharge |            3
 1 | 2018-11-01 | 2018-11-21 | discharge |           20
 2 | 2019-05-15 | 2019-05-20 | discharge |            5
```

Comment: Amazing! Works flawlessly with my data! I was worried I would miss some observations because I have a few instances of user data entry errors where the enddate on a transfer wasn't recorded on time, but instead recorded after the user had a new startdate. The partition seems to take care of that and the observations combine perfectly! 

Thank you so much for the solution and the quick response!